# MySQL Database design and effecient query

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have the following tables:

```
users (id, first_name, last_name)

category (id, name)

rank(id, user_id, rank)
```

Each user can belong to several categories.  And all users are in the rank table and have a value between 0.0 and 1.0, where 0 is the lowest rank and 1 is the highest. I’d like to setup additional tables to create the following webpage:

A visitor to the page (identified by either one of the recorded ids in the user table, or a numeric representation of their ip address) chooses a category and is presented with two randomly chosen users from the users table such that:

1) the visiting user_id has not seen this pairing in a period of 24 hours

2) the two users belong to the chosen category

3) the two users are within 1 rank value of each other.  Let me explain that last criteria - if the ranks were sorted, the two chosen users would have adjacent ranks.

This is a hard one and I can’t for the life of me figure it out how to do this effeciently

I truly appreciate any help on this front.

Thanks

Comment: Are ranks a string, or numeric?

Answer (score 0):

You just need two more tables and the rest go in your website logic.

```
user_category(user_id, category_id)
user_pairing(first_user_id, second_user_id, last_seen)
```

The first table is to represent a ManyToMany relationship between the users and the category, and the second one is for the users pairing.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Yasel, i want to add that you properly want another table

```
candidate(first_user_id, second_user_id);
```

this table is used to pre-calculate the candidates for each user, this `candidate` table is prepopulated every hour/day, so when each `first_user_id, second_user_id` is assigned, this pair is removed from `candidate` table and moved into `user_pairing` table. so each time you only need to query `candidate` table which should be efficient.